# Exsheets counters for new question pairs

Tags: exsheets

When defining a new question/solution pair, is it possible to specify that it should get its own counter?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\NewQuSolPair{query}[name=Query]{exsol}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=se.qu[1],counter-within=section}
\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{question}
  This is an exercise.
\end{question}

\begin{query}
  This is a query, which I'd like to be numbered 1.1
\end{query}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good question. The answer is: that won't be easy... this would require some work but IMHO is worth a feature request.

Answer (score 2):

Until the feature is implemented I use this workaround:

- create a new counter
- create a new environment

PS: You can easily change the style of the new environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\NewQuSolPair{query}[name=Query]{exsol}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=se.qu[1],counter-within=section}

% WORKAROUND
\newcounter{example}[section] % new counter resets every time the section counter is increased
\newenvironment{example}{%
  \refstepcounter{example} % increases the counter by 1; makes it visible for referencing;
  \textbf{Example~\thesection.\theexample}

}{%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{question}
  This is an exercise.
\end{question}

\begin{query}
  This is a query, which I'd like to be numbered 1.1
\end{query}

\begin{example}
  This is a query, which I'd like to be numbered 1.1
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: This accomplishes the goal only insofar as you're not concerned with solutions.  The power of exsheets is that you can pair questions with solutions; your new environment is outside of exsheets' functionality.

Comment: I know. That's way I called it "workaround".

Answer (score 1):

It has been more than 4 years since this question was asked, and the required feature is still lied in TODO list of `exsheets` (check it at the very end of `exsheets.sty`). Hence, here is another workaround:

- new question group are defined in `exsheets`'s way
- new `exsheets` option `pre-counter-hook` is added to insert code just before counter `questino` is stepped, since the value of option `pre-hook`  is inserted too late
- value of counter `question` is changed to and restored from new counter (here `exercise` is used) at the beginning and ending of new question environment, respectively.

This may still break some of the `exsheets` features.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__exsheets_questions_pre_counter_hook_tl
\keys_define:nn { exsheets / question }
  {
    pre-counter-hook .tl_set:N = \l__exsheets_questions_pre_counter_hook_tl
  }

\xpatchcmd \__exsheets_start_question_if_used:n
  { \refstepcounter{question} }
  {
    \l__exsheets_questions_pre_counter_hook_tl
    \refstepcounter{question}
  }
  {}{\fail}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\def\default@counter{question}

% use \default@counter as counter #1
\newcommand\useCounter[1]{%
  \setcounter{@\default@counter}{\value{\default@counter}}%
  \setcounter{\default@counter}{\value{#1}}%
}
% restore \default@counter from counter #1
\newcommand\restoreCounter[1]{%
  \setcounter{#1}{\value{\default@counter}}%
  \setcounter{\default@counter}{\value{@\default@counter}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{exercise}
\newcounter{@question}
\NewQuSolPair
  {exercise}[
    name=Exercies, 
    pre-counter-hook=\useCounter{exercise}, 
    post-hook=\restoreCounter{exercise}]
  {exsolution}[name=Solution to Exercise, print=true]
\RenewQuSolPair
  {question}[name=Question]
  {solution}[name=Solution to Question, print=true]

\begin{document}
\begin{question} q1 \end{question}
\begin{solution} q1 \end{solution}

\begin{exercise} ex1 \end{exercise}

\begin{question} q2 \end{question}

\begin{exercise} ex2 \end{exercise}
\begin{exsolution} ex2 \end{exsolution}
\end{document}
```

[image: exsheets-with-multiple-counters, output]

Comment: `exsheets` is not developed any more. But its successor package `xsim` supports it from the beginning in early 2017. 

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks. Someone asked the same question elsewhere, hence I found this post. I will pass the not-developed-anymore info back.